# Array with same values but unique keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following **array** in php -

```
$arr1 = array("file1.php"=>"R1","file2.php"=>"R2", "file3.php"=>"R1");
```

How can I get the keys for same values and print a different array like the below one

```
$arr2 = array("R1"=>"file1.php,file3.php","R2"=>"file2.php");
```

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Loop over `$arr1` and create `$arr2` as you go while checking for an existing key. Or, were you trying to do this without a loop?

Comment: @Tigger If without a loop then what sort of function should I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate your array  and exchange key value pair(with checking existing key)

```
$arr1 = array("file1.php"=>"R1","file2.php"=>"R2", "file3.php"=>"R1");
$arr2 = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value)
{
    if(isset($arr2[$value]))
        $arr2[$value] .= ",$key";
    else
         $arr2[$value] = $key;
}
print_r($arr2);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/C6DBq)